# How to get the element that jQuery plugin is attached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm using a jquery plugin. Is there any way to get the element that plugin is attached from the plugin's functions?

I tried `this`, `$(this)`. but none of  them worked.

```
$('.myelement').plugin({
    something: function(){
       //in here I want to access $('.myelement)
    } 
});
```

Comment: that will depend on the plugin, which is the plugin used here

Comment: well it has not provided such access, so I thought may be there is a way to access it using javascript power

Comment: In your specific case since you are using an id, why not use `$('#myelement')` instead of `this`.

Comment: Another option is `$('selector').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.plugin({
    something: function() {
      //$this
    }
  });
})
`

Comment: Can you tell us the plugin in question?

Comment: well my example is worng a bit I changed my question

Comment: @ArunPJohny this is the link of the plugin in my website: [http://xn--tgbcfbp0f3bc79i.xn--mgbab2bd/Scripts/persianDatepicker.min.js](http://xn--tgbcfbp0f3bc79i.xn--mgbab2bd/Scripts/persianDatepicker.min.js)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your comment that I upvoted worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the plugin is exposing that information to the callback methods. One workaround if you are dealing with multiple elements are to loop through the element list then call the plugin for each element with a local reference which can be used in the callback

```
$('selector').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.plugin({
    something: function() { //$this 
    }
  });
})
```